# Requesting an array item on a function

Tags: php

If I'd like to extract a string from the beginning till the first (,)
Is it a safe practice to do something like this?

```
$day = explode(',',"Thursday, April 5th, 4:00pm")[0];
```

Instead of doing

```
$dayArray = explode(',',"Thursday, April 5th, 4:00pm");
$day = $dayArray[0];
```

I know I can also do this using `strpos` with `substr`, and I know I can do this with `preg_match`, my question is if it's reliable to request a child, like `[0]`, directly from the function.

Comment: This seems like an opinion based question. I wouldn't use the `)[0]` notation, nor the `preg_match`. I'd use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php to split the CSV string.

Comment: It's "reliable" as long as you're using a version of PHP that supports it (5.4+)

Comment: As @PatrickQ stated, as long as the version of PHP supports [`Function array dereferencing`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), which was introduced in PHP 5.4. However "Reliable" and "safe practice" are highly subjective, as you can not rely on the input or output data being an expected/safe value. If you are referencing this with dates, why not utilize `\DateTime::createFromFormat('l,+')`, which return `false` if it is not in the desired format, then extract the desired text using `->format('l')`? See: https://3v4l.org/YEHvR

Answer (score -1):

Quote from php.net

> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, otherwise an array containing string will be returned.

That means: If you need to be absolutely sure, this code works, you should prevent an empty string passed to explode or check the result for false. Otherwise you could try to access a non existent index.

Did you consider using DateTime::createFromFormat instead? Whether this makes sense, depends on your requirements

Whether the short version is working correctly depends on the PHP-Version you are using (as already mentioned).

Comment: You're confusing the `delimiter` as opposed to the `string` arguments. The OP has the requisite `delimiter` argument as a non-variable  string `,`, where the `string` argument is a variable (presumably date), which in fact would not return `false` if it was supplied as an empty string or even `null`. See: https://3v4l.org/LH930